# Mongoose CRUD app: is it possible to store a favorite as a static document as well as a reference?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am building a CRUD app that utilizes express, mongodb, and mongoose.  I have 2 schemas (I will call them Users and Content for simplicity).    The overall functionality of the app is users create content which can be viewed by all other users.  The content can be edited and deleted by the creator, and also favorited by other users.  I want users to be able to view their favorites in 2 different versions: 1 for the version at the time it was favorited (static content), and 1 for the current "live" version (as the content may have been edited after it was favorited).

I understand how to create both a static favorite (I can copy the content into a user's favorites array) and a live favorite (I can store a reference to the content in a user's favorites array).  What I can't figure out is how to utilize both of these methods at the same time, so a user can click on one of their favorites, and switch between the static and live content.  My idea is that since the copied content in a user's favorites contains a content ObjectId field, I should be able to populate this and access the live content from the static content.  Am I crazy?

```
User {
  (some properties of the user...)

  favorites: [{_id, title, body,...},{_id, title, body,...}...]
}

Content {
  objectId,
  title,
  body,
  (more properties of the content...)
}
```

Right now my structure resembles the above, so I am able to loop through a user's favorites and render the static content (because the actual content was copied into favorites, not just a reference to the content).  What I am wondering is if I can populate the ObjectId within favorites to access the live version of this content, so I can render the live version in addition to the static version.  Is there a best practice for achieving this functionality?

Comment: IMO you can save these "shanpshots" as a casual objects and these will be stored as a simple data. But before you would need to select this "snapshot" and (maybe I'm not sure) transform this selection into a regular JS object which you can assign to another schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this structure might accomplish what you need

```
User{

 _id: ObjectId("USER ID")

 favorites:[ ObjectId("CONTENT 1"), ObjectId("Content 2")]

} 

Content{

  _id:ObjectId("CONTENT 1")

  CreatorID: ObjectId("USER ID")

 OrignalContent:{
        title: title 1 
        body: body 1
 }
 UpdatedContent:{

    title: UpdatedTitle1
    body: UpdatedBody1
 }

}
```

Let me explain what's happening, so `User` is going to have `_id` and `favorites` array which will store the `_id` of the `Content`. Then `Content` will have a `CreatorID` so that we can track who created the content and can edit it. So if `user` wants to see `Content1` you can find it using `_id` and get both `original` and `UpdatedContent`depends which one he wants to see.

This way you won't have to take `snapshots` and copy `fields` in every single object in array, you just keep reference of it and `Updating` and `deleting` would be rather simple.

Make sure when the `owner` of the `Content` sends a update request you only update the `UpdatedContent` not the `orignalContent`.

**Update 2**

As per your comment you want to enable some kind of `versioning`. I might give you my opinion but there might be some better way to do it.

```
User{

 _id: ObjectId("USER ID")

 favorites:[ {ID:ObjectId("CONTENT 1"),version: v1}, {ID:ObjectId("Content 2"),version:v2}]

} 

Content{

  _id:ObjectId("CONTENT 1")

  CreatorID: ObjectId("USER ID")

 OrignalContent:{
        title: title 1 
        body: body 1
 }
 UpdatedContent:{

 v1:{
    title: UpdatedTitle1
    body: UpdatedBody1
   }

   v2:{
    title: UpdatedTitle2
    body: UpdatedBody2

 }

}
```

This approach will store `Duplicate` all the `properties` over and over again (if you have 100 versions, then 100 of similar properties). Alternative could be to store `changed properties only (Metadata)` (this way not every property is repeated, just the changed one).

1st way will allow you to write simple queries to `find` and `update` but will eat memory.

2nd way might save you some memory but `maintaining` and `writing queries` will be bit tedious

Comment: In your example, can you explain how the following would work: what happens if "content 1" is edited, and after it is edited, a user wants to favorite it.  A reference will be pushed to their favorite's array.  If the author edits content 1 again, this middle version of content 1 will be lost, as we will only have the originalContent version, and the newest edited version.  So if the favorited version of the content is neither the original nor the most recent updated, it will be lost.

Comment: To be more clear: "User A" creates "Content 1".  "User A" then edits "Content 1" (originalContent is unchanged, updatedContent is changed).  Now "User B" comes along and wants to favorite what they see as Content 1 (which is updatedContent).  A reference to Content 1 is pushed to "User B" favorites.  "User A" then edits Content 1 a second time.  Now User B is only able to view originalContent (which it may have never seen in the first place), and updatedContent (which may contain unwanted changes).  The content version that was actually favorited is lost.

Comment: I think storing duplicates for each update is the best way for me to do this, however, how will I reference the specific duplicate that is favorited?  For example User A may store updatedContentv2 as favorite, and User B may store updatedContentv3 as favorite.  Is there a specific area of mongoose/mongodb documentation I should be looking into that covers accessing specific duplicates?  Thanks again!

Comment: I already put it in the `favorites array` how you can reference it. I think that would suffice. This way you can get the specific version object by doing `UpdatedContent.v1`

Comment: Ok, I am going to give it a shot.  I also think I figured out how to structure my User so it can store favorites as I originally thought: favorites: [{static: {type: Array}}, {live:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'content'}}].  This way I have my static copied content, and a reference to that same live content.  If I call User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}).populate(???), how do i populate "live"?

Comment: Again this begs for a separate question as this question is limited to setting up the appropriate schema,if you believe you are satisfied with the answer you can mark it correct and ask a separate question regarding populating your database